# Does the arrow function have to always return a value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, return, arrow-functions

Many times when using Eslitn or other linting tools I was getting an error like this:

```
Err: // Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function
```

Does arrow functions always have to return a value?
If the arrow function has to return a value, what's the reason for this?

For example, in this particular piece of code, I don't need to return anything if a condition is not passed. Anyway my linter yiels at me with the mentioned error.

```
const getCookie = name => {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length == 2)
    return parts
      .pop()
      .split(';')
      .shift();
};
```

Comment: No, arrow functions do not have to return a value. ESLint is highly opinionated.

Comment: if you return in 1 path, you should return from them all.

Comment: I believe ESLint would give a warning for regular function as well

Comment: But, at the same time, what are you gaining from it being an arrow function. `function getCookie(name)` would work just as well.

Comment: I'm guessing you're hitting the [consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) rule.  It's not arrow function specific, and as Daniel says - it's designed to make sure you return consistently - ie always or never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, (arrow) functions don't have to return anything but when function is not supposed to be void (i.e return value is expected), it's a good practice to return from every path/return some kind of default value if every other path fails.

```
const getCookie = name => {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length == 2) {
    return parts
      .pop()
      .split(';')
      .shift();
  }

  // default return, for example:
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Do you have references? I mean, I can't get why is this a good pratice

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions do not have to return a value. Expressions need to return values but statements do not. Try a different linter perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

No. But be aware that even if you dont write a return, the function will silently return undefine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Is implicit if you don't use a block for example here:

```
const implicit = i => i * 2;
```

But in case you need to use a block then you need to add a return:

```
const explicit = (i) => {
  if(i > 10) {
    return i * 2;
  }
   return i;
}
```